# Is this the right way to make code working with Python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am updating some Python2 code written by others, and this part:

```
def exec(self, content, query):
      # query = "city_68"
      content = content.strip().strip(',').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
      query = query.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
      query_list = query.split('|')
```

This gives an error in Python3:

```
File "/Users/cong/bexec.py", line 708, in bexec
    content = content.strip().strip(',').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

The parameters content and query are both strings. So I removed the decode part:

```
content = content.strip().strip(',')
# query = query.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Now it doesn't complain any more. Is this safe to do? I guess in Python3 it doesn't need decode() any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. In Python 3, if you have a `str` value, you can assume it is a proper sequence of Unicode code points, not a sequence of bytes that need to be decoded from (say) UTF-8 to a Unicode string. If you have a `bytes` value, you must decode it first in order to get a proper Unicode string.

In Python 2, the boundaries were looser. A `unicode` value was definitely a proper Unicode string (and was renamed `str` in Python 3), while a `str` value could be a "real" ASCII-only string value or arbitrary binary data: you couldn't tell just from the type.

As such, the `str` type supported `encode` and `decode` methods to allow switching between the two sides of the `str` type.

In Python 3, with more strictly defined roles, you can call `str.encode` to  get a `bytes` value, or you can call `bytes.decode` to get a `str` value. You cannot decode a `str` or further encode a `bytes`. `str.decode` and `bytes.encode` simply do not exist.

---

In some sense, all files are binary files: they consist of a stream of bytes. What we call a text file is just a file whose bytes are intended to be decoded using a particular text decoder, like ASCII or UTF-8, as opposed to something like a JPEG decoder, or a JVM, or your CPU itself.

When you use `open` to open a file in text mode (the default), its `read` method returns `str` values, resulting from applying file object's decoder to the raw bytes read from the file.

When you use `open` to open a file in binary mode, its `read` method returns `bytes` values, the raw bytes being left undecoded for you to handle as you see fit.